# How to add buttons like minimize,maximize and close to a div using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to add buttons like minimize,maximize and close to a div using javascript/jquery?
Please provide easier solution..

Comment: This is pretty simple    , show us what you've tried. ( or at least - where is the DIV) ( jsbin)

Comment: agreed with Royi Namir....code snippet will help you get a quicker replies!!

Comment: I just googled exact question and saw two similar questions on Stack Overflow except they don't have *close*. And the [first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20812794/242583) for this question, the script part is virtually [the same](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16164752/242583) for one of those questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Minimize / Maximize div's with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164672/minimize-maximize-divs-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
<div class="content">Some content!</div>

<button class="btn-minimize"></button>
```

Script

```
$(".btn-minimize").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-plus');
    $(".content").slideToggle();
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uzmjq/)