# how to add close minimize full screen button to bootstrap panel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i want to add a close and minmize  button to hide and close the body panel pannel  and to full screen button to every bootsrap panel in the page using jquery

```
    <div class="panel panel-primary">


        <div class="panel-heading">

            <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>  Number Of Tickets Reported In The Billing Unit (Today)</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="flot-chart">
                <div id="BillPhChart"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure of what you want. Could you please elaborate your question/body properly?

Comment: the problem that i want these option to aplly only on the specifc panel,because in my page there is multiple panel and when i hit toggle all pannel minimize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use jQuery to perform these tasks. Then the buttons should simply call the corresponding jQuery functions.

Here are some quick hints I just found :

[Minimize / Maximize div's with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164672/minimize-maximize-divs-with-jquery)

http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/fullscreen/

Here is an example for the button :

```
<a href="#" class="btn"><i class="icon-white icon-plus"></i></a>
```

The `href` being the jQuery function.

EDIT:
To individually trigger the panels, give each one of them an unique id and create a JavaScript function that calls the jQuery using the id selector to identify it.

```
$( "#myID" )
```

You can find the id of the panel that triggered the event using this :

```
event.target.id
```

Comment: i know that ,the problem that i want these option to aplly only on the specifc panel,because in my page there is multiple panel and when i hit toggle all pannel minimize

Comment: Mainly if you are already using jquery, why inline javascript code?